# getStringArray() causing crash on 8.1 Google Pixels 2s and 2 XLs

Tags: java, android, android-resources

Google crash logs are showing that the following line is causing a crash on 8.1 devices, all of which are Google Pixel 2 and Pixel 2 XLs.

```
String[] strings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.voice_intros);
```

Here is a crash log that accompanies it when I try to run the app on my Pixel 2 XL:

[image]

I'm sorry this is a screenshot, I couldn't get stack overflow to format it very well. Does anyone know what could cause this? The string array I am trying to access is very large because it is Base64 encoded audio. However, this hasn't been a problem on any other devices/Android versions.

Comment: if your string is same for all devices you could use preferences instead of resource

Comment: We are loading them into preferences from resources. Due to the format of the string, if we put it in a java file, the string would be misinterpreted and would result in hundreds of compile-time errors (because of quotation marks an and slashes in the string) It's a massive string, so fixing all those errors would be extremely tedious.

Comment: you can put it in a file in `raw` or `asset` resources. put your encoded audio in a file there